# Sampling in F# : is Set adequate?

Tags: f#, set, sampling

I have an array of items, from which I'd like to sample.

I was under the impression that a Set would the a good structure to sample from, in a fold where I'd give back the original or a modified set with the retrieved element missing depending if I want replacement of not.
However, there seems to no method to retrieve an element directly from a Set.

Is there something I am missing ? or should I use Set of indices, along with a surrogate function that starts at some random `position < Set.count` and goes up until it finds a member ?

That is, something along this line

```
module Seq =
    let modulo (n:int) start = 
        let rec next i = seq { yield (i + 1)%n ; yield! next (i+1)}
        next start

module Array =
    let Sample (withReplacement:bool) seed (entries:'T array) = 
        let prng, indexes = new Random(seed), Set(Seq.init (entries |> Array.length) id)
        Seq.unfold (fun set  -> let N = set |> Set.count
                                let next = Seq.modulo N (prng.Next(N)) |> Seq.truncate N |> Seq.tryFind(fun i -> set |> Set.exists ((=) i))
                                if next.IsSome then
                                    Some(entries.[next.Value], if withReplacement then set else Set.remove next.Value set)
                                else
                                    None)
```

Edit : Tracking positively what I gave, instead of tracking what I still can give would make it simpler and more efficient.

Comment: _"there seems to no method to retrieve an element directly from a Set"_ Are you looking for [`contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340362.aspx)?

Comment: no I was looking for something that gives me back a element, either from an index (not possible, otherwise set would have to maintain a correspondance table) or just an element at random (I guess the tree would have to maintain a count of its children). I somehow was expecting that you could sample from a set, but this probably is me being overexposed to statistics those days.

Comment: An array would be perfect for indexed random access.

Comment: yes, but what happens is I have something like 300k rows of stuff, of which I want to sample like 1k, and we are having some memory issues already..

Comment: Then you want to randomly sample a sequence?

Comment: exactly, so I dont quite need the random access. I think I'll just write some "Samplable Set" in the future, where I just keep a count somewhere. that would allow me to sample from it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sampling *without* replacement, you could just permute the source seq and take however many elements you want to sample

```
let sampleWithoutReplacement n s =
    let a = Array.ofSeq s
    seq { for i = a.Length downto 1 do
              let j = rnd.Next i
              yield a.[j]
              a.[j] <- a.[i - 1] }
    |> Seq.take n
```

To sample *with* replacement, just pick a random element n times from the source seq

```
let sampleWithReplacement n s =
    let a = Array.ofSeq s
    Seq.init n (fun _ -> a.[rnd.Next(a.Length)])
```

These may not be the most efficient methods with huge data sets however

Comment: yes I realized if I made the hypothesis of having an array, it would be direct. I started with this notion of a set. my question is not meaningful as phrased.

Comment: In your second section, should it be "To sample _without_ replacement..." ?

Comment: @paul no it seems correct. however I'd use Seq.unfold there, as it is just an infinite sequence. adding the initial list is superfluous

Comment: @nicolas I should have matched the code up with the comments; the first part says "For sampling with replacement" whereas the code there says `sampleWithoutReplacement` and that's the one I should have pointed out.

Comment: Also changed the sampleWithReplacement to not use an initial [1..n] list as suggested

Comment: nice. so that the generation to come will learn from my stupidity.

Comment: actually, Seq.unfold would be even  better.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing our comments...if you want to randomly sample a sequence without slurping the entire thing into memory you could generate a set of random indices the size of your desired sample (not too different from what you already have):

```
let rand count max = 
  System.Random() 
    |> Seq.unfold (fun r -> Some(r.Next(max), r))
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.take count
    |> set

let takeSample sampleSize inputSize input =
  let indices = rand sampleSize inputSize
  input
    |> Seq.mapi (fun idx x -> 
      if Set.contains idx indices then Some x else None)
    |> Seq.choose id

let inputSize = 100000
let input = Seq.init inputSize id
let sample = takeSample 50 inputSize input
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList sample)
```